# SQL Multiple Format Dates

Tags: sql, sqlite

In a database, there are multiple formats of dates in a single column. Is there a way (with this in mind) to get all the dates before x (with x being the date of my choice). I think all the dates are either dd/mm/yyyy, dd/mm/yy or yy-dd-mm but cannot guarantee this.

Context: I am running the SQL from `sqlite3` in Python which (for some reason) says it cannot find the `CONVERT` function (whether or not this is me, I don't know).

Comment: There is no such thing as "multiple formats of dates in a single column".  There are just strings in the column, some of which can be interpreted as dates.  The standard format for SQLite text columns that represent dates is YYYY-MM-DD.  If the intention is for the column to contain dates, that is the only format that should be in the column.

Comment: As Gordon said, this can't happen. Is this a long, concatenated string of dates (which is a string) or several individual dates (stored as dates or worse, stored as strings) that are being concatenated?

Comment: Also, I don't know if SQLITE has `CONVERT()`, but it should have a `CAST()`.